# How to delete multiple blobs in one shot GS bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

One blob delete:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#prereq-code-samples

I have a list of blobs like below:

```
['/26/06/2022/updwx/asr-mobile/1656287241091_hb.opus',
 '/26/06/2022/rrvjz/asr-mobile/1656287214693_hb.opus',
 '/26/06/2022/ledum/asr-mobile1656286851212_hb.opus',
 '/26/06/2022/atveh/asr-mobile1656286708558_hb.opus',
 '/25/06/2022/dlivh/asr-mobile/1656170162472_hb.opus',]
```

I don't want to run for loop to delete one by one.

All blobs belong to one bucket.

Comment: If you consult the API documentation you will find there is no API to multi-delete. You could write your own function to perform asynchronous HTTP calls to delete multiple blobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [delete_blobs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.delete_blobs) to delete multiple blobs in your bucket.

**For example:**

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('insert-bucket-name-here')
items = ["26/06/2022/updwx/asr-mobile/1656287241091_hb.opus","26/06/2022/rrvjz/asr-mobile/1656287214693_hb.opus"]

bucket.delete_blobs(items)
print ("files deleted")
```

**NOTE:**
**Proper listing of items:**

- `folder/filename.jpg` - if it's inside a folder
- `/folder/filename.jpg` - adding / in front of folder won't work
- `filename.jpg` - if it's in the root folder of your bucket

**Proper listing of bucket name:**

- Do not include `gs://` in front of your bucket name

Comment: I want to delete specific files and not the complete folder or bucket.

Comment: @AnkitSingh I updated the answer to your question